# Rsync Bandwidth usage explination

Tags: linux, rsync

I have an rsync script that currently backs up from one internal hard drive to another, I am looking at adding an offsite backup ( rsync over ssh ), My question is what would the bandwith usage be for that. Here is a sample output of what my log shows

```
sent 86511816 bytes  received 12798 bytes  5967214.76 bytes/sec
total size is 16458790438  speedup is 190.22
```

I am trying to figure out if I add this offsite will it be sending 15 GB ( total size is ... ) or .08 GB ( sent ... )

Answer (score 0):

I think it will only be 0.08GB. Total size is the size of the entire backup.

So it is something like total = (sent + received) * speedup.